# AngularJS route provider (.otherwise)

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('app').config(appRte);

function appRte($routeProvider, $locationProvider, storiesURL) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'stories.html',
            controller: 'StoryController as StoryCtrl',
            resolve: {
                storyDataPromiseObject: ['StoryData', function(StoryData) {
                    return StoryData.getStories(storiesURL);
                }]
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

When I go to my domain root http://website.com/ it works fine, but if I go to http://website.com/anything I get an error. I'd like the website to redirect to / instead. Is this possible?

Comment: This is an issue you can't directly address within the angular routing system - your index page isn't getting touched at all when you visit other pages. What's your stack? A better solution involves Apache or Nginx configs.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What do you mean that my index page isn't getting touched? Thank you. I'm using nginx and I can setup the directive to redirect there ... I was hoping to accomplish this w/Angular. I take you at your word that it can't be done this way, but I'd also like to understand why. Thanks again ...

Comment: did you set your base href ?

Comment: Do you have any errors on developer console (at your http://website.com/ ) ?. I dont see anywhere you put `ngRoute` as your module dependancy. What angular version are you using?

Comment: No errors. ngRoute is a dependency in my module declaration. The page works fine, but when I attempt to navigate to a URL that doesn't exist, I wanted it to default to the one that is working. Instead I get a 404.

Comment: But more specifically, no errors on my console.